# Adding slots to a 2D array

Tags: java

I need to create a method which adds a card to a Flashcard box which is a 2 dimensional array that I have created. It has three String parameters (word, definition, subject). 
The  method will take three String parameters – information for a new Flashcard. It will 
return a boolean value indicating if the card was successfully added to the box. 
It will try to add a card in the following manner: 
If the subject the card is for is in the box, and the card is not already in the box, then I can add the card to the box. If I want to add the card, and there isn’t enough room in the row that corresponds to the subject, then I need to grow the array so that each subject has room 
for one more card. If the subject the card is for is not in the box, then I need to store the card in the next empty row (which would be analogous to adding the subject to the box). If there isn’t an empty row, then I need to grow the array and add a row.If the card is already in the box, then I'm not able to add it to the row. Please help, I am making this as a study tool.

Here is the pseudo code written out that it needs to follow:

```
    public FlashcardBoxAddCardHelp
{
   public boolean addCard(String subject, String word, String definition)
    {
       Flashcard toAdd = new Flashcard(subject, word, definition);
       for(loop through rows)
        {
         for(loop through columns)
            {
               if(current card is the same as the card to add)
                {
                   return false;
                }
            }          
        }

        int subjectIndex = -1;

        for(loop through rows)
        {
           if(currentRow has subject I want)
            {
               subjectIndex = currentRow;
            }
        }

        if(subject is in the box) // 
        {
           if(there is room in that row)
            {
               add the card to the first free slot in that row
            }else // do this last!
            {
            //   grow the array to add a column
            //  add the card to the new column for your subjIndex row
            //  update the counts to keep track of how many columns you have   
                    //       and how many columns you have room for
            }
        }else
        {
           if(there is room for a new subject)
            {
               add the card to the first free row
            }else // do this last!
            {
             //  grow the array to add a row
             // add the card to the first slot in that new row
             // update the counts to keep track of how many rows you have 
                     //     and how many rows you have room for
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to be using an ArrayList, not a primative array. With an ArrayList you can add and remove items without having to worry about "growing or shrinking the array". An ArrayList uses a primative array internally and does all this work for you.

Comment: @SlipperySeal I would go further and suggest even using a map for the initial subject declaration. It would be a map of maps with map.get("subject").get("word") would return the definition and adding a value within a subject would just be adding a key-value pair.

Comment: agreed. and there are various kinds of maps which store values in insert order / natural order etc, if this is important

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can't really add a slot in an array, you have to create an array with a length 1 longer than the array before, and then set the old array equal to the new one as well as copy over all the old information into the new array. It might be easier to use an ArrayList of ArrayLists. Try this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<FlashCard>> subjects = new ArrayList<ArrayList<FlashCard>>();
```

Then when you want to add a flashcard:

```
if (subject there) // Find subject using for loops
{
    subject = /*that subject*/;
    subject.add(flashcard);
}
else
{
    ArrayList<FlashCard> subject = new ArrayList<FlashCard>();
    subject.add(flashcard);
    subjects.add(subject);
}
```

Comment if you want clarification. i.e. the rest of the finding code, but it's pretty simple.

Comment: Will you show how to increase each row and column by one and then how to copy the array into the newly resized array?

Comment: Why an array? Use an array list unless this is a school project and you __have__ to use arrays.